# Pause and Unpause AS2 animations

Tags: animation, actionscript-2

I am trying to figure out a way to pause and unpause animation of my video. In as3, this is an easy task by using `stage.framerate = 0`, but as2 doesn't allow for that. The major issue is the animation has only 1 frame and all animation is operated via `actionscript2`.

Here is my example code:

```
Tween1();
function Tween1(){
    setTimeout(theTween, 1000); //tween executes after 1000 milliseconds
    function theTween(){
        //animation stuff here
         //Move X position of ball instance
         var myTween:Tween = new Tween(ball, "_x", Regular.easeOut, -40, 71, 1, true);
         //Rotate button 360 degrees
         var myTween:Tween = new Tween(button, "_rotation", Regular.easeOut, -360, 0, 1, true);
         // fade in logo
         var myTween:Tween = new Tween(logo, "_alpha", Regular.easeOut, 0, 100, 1, true);
        //call Tween 2
        Tween(2); //calls next animation tween
}

    function Tween2(){
        setTimeout(theTween, 5000); //tweene executes after 5000 milliseconds
        function theTween(){
            //more animation stuff
            // fade out logo
            var myTween:Tween = new Tween(logo, "_alpha", Regular.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);
            Tween(3); //calls next animation tween
    }
```

I have created a movie clip icon that changes states between play and pause symbols but I have no idea how to pause and unpause the execution of these functions. Can anybody provide a way to do so? Here is my current code for changing the States of my `Pause_mc`

```
var buttonState = 0;

pause.onMouseDown =  function () {
    if (buttonState == 0) {
        buttonState = 1;
        pause.gotoAndStop(2); //moves movieclip to pause symbol
        //need code to pause tween executions
    } else {
        buttonState = 0;
        pause.gotoAndStop(1); //moves movieclip to play symbol
        //need code to resume tween executions
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using setInterval(); instead of setTimeout();  & some sort of switch for play & stop state(s).

eg. when it gets to tween function 'if play false' it repeats interval until play is true.

or maybe tweenInstance.stop(); could help.

eg.

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(img1_mc, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.None.easeNone, img1_mc._width,         Stage.width, 8, true);

myTween.onMotionFinished = function() {
myTween.start();
}; 

stopTween_btn.onRelease = function() {
 myTween.stop();
}; 

resumeTween_btn.onRelease = function() {
 myTween.resume();
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how the file was built. Sorry for the confusion. I added additional code to help clarify how my animations are functioning. Every time a function is called it performs a set of actions and then that function calls the next tween function to perform another set of actions.

Comment: I have updated my Answer, Since my Flash CC updated I can't access any as2 features anymore to test,  however I think this will help.